# How to get the New Password and Confirm Password when user change the password in WindowsXP(or Windows7)

Tags: windows, passwords

I want to write a program that can capture the password when users change their password in Windows, is there any DLL or Interface that MicroSoft has provided?

For example, if I want to get the username and password, I can implement a GINA.DLL.

But how can I get the New Password and Confirm Password when user change the pas

Comment: You can edit your question instead of writing it as comment

Comment: Credential manager: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374792(v=vs.85).aspx